# React-Native build in Visual Studio Code unable to connect with remote debugger timeout while connecting to remote debugger in windows

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, react-native, react-native-debugger

I was building react-native on vscode today and got the same error as the image.
I've searched around, but it didn't help much as I only had answers for building in terminal.
I want to know the solution when building in vscode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDx8a.png)

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Just try the below

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

and then reload the app